# complex numbers. help in proof that $e^{-it}=1/e^{it}$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

I need to show that $e^{-it}=\frac{1}{e^{it}}$. 
but I don't understand what needs to be proven, it seems trivial to me. If anyone could help me. 
Is the claim true even if t is not real?
Thank you

Comment: How do you define $e^z$ for complex $z$?

Comment: Note that the question is whether this is true for t real and also for complex number

Comment: It is true. But proof of it depends on what definition(s) of $e^z$ you use - there are many. And for example it's much simpler to proof this property if exponent is defined using Euler formula then say from series or differential equation.

Answer (score 3):

You have$$e^{it}\cdot e^{-it}=e^{it-it}=e^0=1$$and therefore$$e^{-it}=\frac1{e^{it}}.$$

Comment: o.k. thank you. but is it true even t isn't  real number?

Comment: Yes. I did not use *at all* the fact that $t$ is a real number. This holds for *every* complex number $t$.

Answer (score 2):

From Euler's formula,
$$e^{-it} = \cos(t)+i\sin(-t) = \cos(t)-i\sin(t).$$
Also,
$$e^{it} = \cos(t)+i\sin(t).$$
Now, compute the product
$$e^{it} \cdot e^{-it}.$$
You find that the answer is $1$.  This shows that $e^{it}$ is the reciprocal of $e^{-it}$.

Answer (score 1):

Using Eulers formula,

$$\cos(x) + i\sin(x) = e^{ix}$$

$$\cos(x) - i\sin(x) = e^{-ix}$$

Multiply the two equations and you’re done (work out the left hand side containing trigonometric quantities which should turn out to be $1$, while the right hand side leave it as $e^{ix}e^{-ix}$

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of the complex number $e^{t\cdot i}$ is, by definition, another complex number $e^{u+v\cdot i}$ such that 
$$
e^{t\cdot i}\cdot e^{u+v\cdot i}=1
$$
On the other hand we know that
$$
e^{t\cdot i}\cdot e^{u+v\cdot i}=e^{u+(t+v)\cdot i} \quad \mbox{ and } \quad 1=e^{0+0\cdot i}
$$
Equating the right sides of these two equations we have
$$
e^{u+(t+v)\cdot i}=e^{0+0\cdot i}\implies u=0 \quad \mbox{ and } \quad t+v=0
$$
Consequently we have $ v = -t $ and therefore 
$$
\frac{1}{e^{t\cdot i}}=e^{-t\cdot i}
$$